# Анимация SVG и anime.js

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация, svg-animation, anime.js

Увидел такую интересную анимацию в библиотеке [animejs.com](https://animejs.com/).
Так понял, что каждая буква описана в:

```
<path class="el" d="M58 80V50.12C57.7 41.6 51.14 35 43 35a15 15 0 0 0 0 30h7.5v15H43a30 30 0 1 1 0-60c16.42 0 29.5 13.23 30 29.89V80H58z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 83.7591px;" stroke-dasharray="316.85528564453125"></path>
```

Вопрос в том, как это получить?

Пробую сделать что-то в этом роде, только со своим текстом:

```js
anime({
  targets: '.line-drawing-demo .lines path',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 1500,
  delay: function(el, i) { return i * 250 },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div class="demo-content align-center line-drawing-demo">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 280 100">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1" class="lines">
        <path class="el" d="M58 80V50.12C57.7 41.6 51.14 35 43 35a15 15 0 0 0 0 30h7.5v15H43a30 30 0 1 1 0-60c16.42 0 29.5 13.23 30 29.89V80H58z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 83.7591px;" stroke-dasharray="316.85528564453125"></path>
        <path class="el" d="M73 80V20H58v60h15z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 77.4613px;" stroke-dasharray="150"></path>
        <path class="el" d="M58 80V49.77C58.5 33.23 71.58 20 88 20a30 30 0 0 1 30 30v30h-15V50a15 15 0 0 0-15-15c-8.14 0-14.7 6.6-15 15.12V80H58zm75 0V20h-15v60h15z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 337.09px;" stroke-dasharray="441.1739501953125"></path>
        <path class="el" d="M118 80V49.77C118.5 33.23 131.58 20 148 20a30 30 0 0 1 30 30v30h-15V50a15 15 0 0 0-15-15c-8.14 0-14.7 6.6-15 15.12V80h-15zm-7.5-60a7.5 7.5 0 1 1-7.48 8v-1c.25-3.9 3.5-7 7.48-7z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 318.34px;" stroke-dasharray="338.3053894042969"></path>
        <path class="el" d="M133 65a15 15 0 0 1-15-15v-7.5h-15V50a30 30 0 0 0 30 30V65zm30 15V49.77C163.5 33.23 176.58 20 193 20a30 30 0 0 1 30 30v30h-15V50a15 15 0 0 0-15-15c-8.14 0-14.7 6.6-15 15.12V80h-15z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 406.87px;" stroke-dasharray="406.8699035644531"></path>
        <path class="el" d="M238 65a15 15 0 0 1 0-30c8.1 0 14.63 6.53 15 15h-15v15h30V49.89C267.5 33.23 254.42 20 238 20a30 30 0 0 0 0 60V65z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 301.856px;" stroke-dasharray="301.8561706542969"></path>
        <path class="el" d="M260.48 65a7.5 7.5 0 1 1-7.48 8v-1c.26-3.9 3.5-7 7.48-7z" style="stroke-dashoffset: 47.1289px;" stroke-dasharray="47.128875732421875"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: @MaximLensky а какой лучше всего подойдет для этих целей? или вообще без разницы?

Comment: Что означает аттрибт d="n n n" у тэга path можно посмотреть вот здесь - https://eugene.stormway.ru/works/programmer/html/svg-path

Comment: @user355827 [Добавил ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086067/28748) с использование anime.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За всю анимацию отвечает stroke-dasharray который анимирауется в keyframes

А сам path я получил в inkscape

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Anime.js просто это облегчает

Подобный пример в сниппете

```css
path {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.3;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0 500;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1000;
  animation: draw 4s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes draw {
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 200 200;
  }
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0 500;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1000;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #999;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 247 200 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <g stroke-dashoffset=".18549999">
   <path d="m16.388392 273.68927q-2.45842-0.93707-3.32934-1.96233-0.870921-1.03628-0.870921-2.77812 0-2.23794 1.43316-3.51676t3.935677-1.27882q1.135504 0 2.271007 0.26459 1.135504 0.25355 2.248959 0.76067v3.175q-1.04731-0.73863-2.127691-1.12448-1.080382-0.38585-2.138716-0.38585-1.1796 0-1.807986 0.47405-0.628385 0.47404-0.628385 1.35599 0 0.6835 0.451996 1.1355 0.463021 0.44097 1.918229 0.98116l1.400087 0.52917q1.984375 0.72761 2.921441 1.92925 0.937066 1.20165 0.937066 3.03169 0 2.49149-1.477257 3.72621-1.466232 1.2237-4.442795 1.2237-1.223698 0-2.45842-0.29765-1.223698-0.28664-2.370226-0.8599v-3.36241q1.300868 0.92604 2.513542 1.37803 1.223698 0.452 2.414323 0.452 1.201649 0 1.863107-0.54019 0.661459-0.55122 0.661459-1.53238 0-0.73863-0.440972-1.28984-0.440973-0.56224-1.27882-0.88195z"/>
   <path d="m31.954711 265.05724v3.50572h4.222309v2.48047h-4.222309v5.84289q0 0.82682 0.396875 1.19062 0.4079 0.35278 1.344966 0.35278h2.480468v2.48047h-2.711979q-2.778125 0-3.759288-0.88195-0.981163-0.89297-0.981163-3.29627v-5.68854h-3.152952v-2.48047h3.152952v-3.50572z"/>
   <path d="m45.646899 275.1114q-1.807986 0-2.524566 0.46302t-0.71658 1.5875q0 0.83785 0.496094 1.33394 0.496093 0.4961 1.344965 0.4961 1.278819 0 1.984375-0.95912 0.705556-0.97014 0.705556-2.70095v-0.22049zm4.497917-1.24574v7.04453h-3.208073v-1.37804q-0.584289 0.8158-1.499306 1.25677t-2.017448 0.44097q-2.105642 0-3.285243-1.11345-1.168576-1.11346-1.168576-3.10886 0-2.16076 1.400086-3.18602 1.400087-1.03629 4.332553-1.03629h2.237934v-0.54019q0-0.78272-0.573264-1.1796-0.56224-0.4079-1.66467-0.4079-1.157553 0-2.248959 0.29766-1.080382 0.28663-2.259982 0.92604v-2.75608q1.069357-0.44097 2.171788-0.65043 1.10243-0.20946 2.337153-0.20946 3.009635 0 4.222309 1.2237 1.223698 1.22369 1.223698 4.37665z"/>
   <path d="m63.208619 280.2818q-0.815799 0.47405-1.752865 0.70556-0.937066 0.24253-2.017448 0.24253-2.855295 0-4.464844-1.71979-1.609548-1.71979-1.609548-4.7625 0-3.05373 1.620573-4.77352 1.620573-1.73082 4.475868-1.73082 0.992187 0 1.907205 0.23151 0.926041 0.23151 1.841059 0.71658v2.95451q-0.705556-0.60633-1.554428-0.92604-0.837847-0.33073-1.74184-0.33073-1.576476 0-2.425347 1.00321-0.848872 1.00322-0.848872 2.8553t0.848872 2.84427q0.848871 0.99219 2.425347 0.99219 0.937066 0 1.752865-0.30868 0.815798-0.31971 1.543403-0.95912z"/>
   <path d="m67.012003 263.75637h3.230122v9.00685l3.880555-4.20026h3.913629l-4.674306 4.60816 4.938889 7.73907h-3.571875l-3.384462-5.77674-1.10243 1.05833v4.71841h-3.230122z"/>
   <path d="m85.46669 270.88909q-1.157552 0-1.819011 1.02526-0.661458 1.01424-0.661458 2.83325t0.661458 2.84427q0.661459 1.01424 1.819011 1.01424 1.168576 0 1.830034-1.01424 0.661459-1.02526 0.661459-2.84427t-0.661459-2.83325q-0.661458-1.02526-1.830034-1.02526zm-5.710591 3.85851q0-2.98759 1.543403-4.72943 1.554427-1.75286 4.167188-1.75286 2.623784 0 4.167187 1.75286 1.554427 1.74184 1.554427 4.72943t-1.554427 4.74045q-1.543403 1.74184-4.167187 1.74184-2.612761 0-4.167188-1.74184-1.543403-1.75286-1.543403-4.74045z"/>
   <path d="m104.96869 268.56296-3.92465 12.34723h-3.979778l-3.924653-12.34723h3.274219l2.634809 9.63525 2.645833-9.63525z"/>
   <path d="m117.98839 280.30385q-1.12448 0.46302-2.29306 0.69453-1.16857 0.23151-2.46944 0.23151-3.09783 0-4.74045-1.65364-1.6316-1.66467-1.6316-4.78455 0-3.02066 1.57648-4.77353 1.57647-1.75286 4.29948-1.75286 2.74505 0 4.25538 1.6316 1.52135 1.62057 1.52135 4.57508v1.31189h-8.36745q0.011 1.45521 0.8599 2.17179 0.84887 0.71658 2.53559 0.71658 1.11345 0 2.19384-0.3197 1.08038-0.31971 2.25998-1.01424zm-2.73403-6.94531q-0.0221-1.27882-0.66146-1.92926-0.62838-0.66145-1.8631-0.66145-1.11346 0-1.77492 0.6835-0.66146 0.67249-0.78272 1.91823z"/>
   <path d="m132.11053 271.96947q-0.52917-0.48506-1.24575-0.7276-0.70555-0.24253-1.55443-0.24253-1.02526 0-1.79696 0.3638-0.76068 0.35278-1.1796 1.03628-0.26458 0.41893-0.37483 1.01424-0.0992 0.59531-0.0992 1.80799v5.68854h-3.23013v-12.34723h3.23013v1.91823q0.47404-1.05833 1.4552-1.63159 0.98117-0.58429 2.29306-0.58429 0.66146 0 1.28984 0.16536 0.63941 0.15434 1.21268 0.46302z"/>
   <path d="m141.15046 267.48258v1.08038h3.79236v2.48047h-3.79236v9.86676h-3.23012v-9.86676h-2.99861v-2.48047h2.99861v-0.85989q0-2.22691 0.92604-3.08681 0.92604-0.85989 3.43958-0.85989h2.65686v2.48047h-2.52456q-0.72761 0-0.99219 0.26458-0.25356 0.26458-0.27561 0.98116z"/>
   <path d="m150.85184 275.76184v-9.525h-3.27421v-2.48047h6.50434v12.00547q0 1.4552 0.45199 2.06154 0.452 0.60634 1.53238 0.60634h2.57969v2.48047h-3.48368q-2.30408 0-3.30729-1.19063-1.00322-1.19062-1.00322-3.95772z"/>
   <path d="m166.95835 270.88909q-1.15755 0-1.81901 1.02526-0.66146 1.01424-0.66146 2.83325t0.66146 2.84427q0.66146 1.01424 1.81901 1.01424 1.16858 0 1.83004-1.01424 0.66145-1.02526 0.66145-2.84427t-0.66145-2.83325q-0.66146-1.02526-1.83004-1.02526zm-5.71059 3.85851q0-2.98759 1.5434-4.72943 1.55443-1.75286 4.16719-1.75286 2.62379 0 4.16719 1.75286 1.55443 1.74184 1.55443 4.72943t-1.55443 4.74045q-1.5434 1.74184-4.16719 1.74184-2.61276 0-4.16719-1.74184-1.5434-1.75286-1.5434-4.74045z"/>
   <path d="m173.74933 268.56296h2.68993l1.46624 9.45886 1.33394-6.22873h2.61276l1.31189 6.22873 1.48828-9.45886h2.68993l-2.23793 12.34723h-3.06476l-1.4993-6.41615-1.48829 6.41615h-3.06475z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: я скачал Inkscape (вроде как векторный редактор), но не понимаю как получить  path из буквы

Answer (score 4):

> я скачал Inkscape (вроде как векторный редактор), но не понимаю как
>   получить path из буквы –

- Выбираете на панели инструментов - `Создавать и править текстовые
  объекты` - <kbd>F8</kbd>
- Выбираете шрифт, размер шрифта
- Пишите слово
- Стрелкой `Выделить и трансформировать объекты` - <kbd>F1</kbd>
  выделяете текст
- В верхнем меню редактора выбираете **контур / оконтурить объект**
  <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+C</kbd>
- Сохраняете файл, копируете `path` для каждой буквы

### Вот так получилось для слова `Stack`

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="560" height="200" viewBox="0 0 280 100">
<style>
.el{
     stroke:black;
 stroke-width:2;
 fill:none;
 
}

</style> 
 <g aria-label="STACK" transform="scale(0.83640582,1.1955919)" >
    <path class="el" d="M81.1 21.5C81.1 33.9 59.2 31.7 62.5 19.4 47.6 19.1 60.9 36.3 61.2 44.1 63.3 54.4 53.3 61.8 44.2 63.4 32.2 65.9 18.4 65.6 7.9 58.6-2.4 50.7 8 37.1 18.8 38.9c6-0.3 12.1-0.1 18.1-0.2 1.5 3.1 4.4 7.2-1.3 5.7-5.9 0.2-14-1.3-17.1 5.1-0.2 10.9 16.3 11.7 23.6 7.1 9.2-6.3 1.7-17.9-0.5-25.9-4.4-11.1 7.7-18.4 17.4-17.6 6.8 0.5 15.3-2.3 20.4 3.7 1.1 1.3 1.7 3.1 1.7 4.8zM141.1 12.9" />
    <path class="el" d="m141.1 12.9c-1.6 3-3.2 6-4.8 8.9-4.4 0-8.8 0-13.2 0-4.2 11.3-7.7 22.9-12.5 34-4.4 8.4-14.5 6.9-22.4 7-5.1 0-10.2 0-15.3 0 1.1-7.2 7.7-10 14-7.6 3.7 0.6 7.3 1.2 11 1.7C102.1 45.2 106.2 33.5 110.4 21.8 102.1 22.1 93.7 21.2 85.5 22.5 79 21.5 75 37.4 80.4 33.6 85.3 20.8 106.5 32.5 95.8 42.6 86.4 50 69.1 42.3 71.3 29.5 72.8 17 86.8 11.8 97.9 12.9c14.4 0 28.8 0 43.2 0z" />
    <path class="el" d="m223.6 38.7c-2.4 7.7-11.5 5.3-17.6 5.7-4 0-8.1 0-12.1 0-2.2 6.2-4.4 12.3-6.7 18.5-4.2 0-8.5 0-12.7 0 2.2-6.2 4.4-12.3 6.7-18.5-3.6 0-7.3 0-10.9 0-9.6 11.6-23.2 23.9-39.5 21.1-14.5-2.7-5.9-20.6 4.7-22.5 9.7-4.2 20.5-4.4 30.9-4.3 7.2-8.6 14.3-17.2 21.5-25.8 5.7 0 11.4 0 17.1 0-3.1 8.6-6.1 17.2-9.2 25.8 9.3 0 18.5 0 27.8 0zM190.6 18.8c-5.2 6.6-10.4 13.3-15.5 19.9 2.8-0.8 8.1 2 8.7-2.1 2.3-5.9 4.5-11.9 6.8-17.8zm-29 25.6c-8.4 0-22.8 0.9-22.9 11.9 7.5 5.5 18.1-6.6 22.9-11.9z" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path class="el" d="m261.8 21.6c0.1 12.7-22.1 10.4-18.8-2.1-13.2 1.1-22.9 17.2-18.4 29.5 5 10 17.5 8 26.9 8.2 3.1 0.5 12.1-1.9 7.1 3.5-5.6 3.8-12.8 1.6-19.2 2.2-10.9 0-25.4-1.6-30-13.2-4.4-15 8.4-29.3 21.8-34.1 7.9-2.9 16.8-3.4 25-2 3.1 1.4 5.7 4.5 5.6 8z" />
    <path class="el" d="m330.7 12.9c-9.7 8.6-19.3 17.2-29 25.8 8.1-1.9 8.7 6.6 5.5 11.9-0.6 2.9-4.5 8 1.1 6.5 3.8 0 7.6 0 11.4 0-3 7.8-12.7 5.2-19.3 5.7-5.9 1.5-10.8-3.2-7.2-8.9 1.2-3.7 2.4-7.3 3.7-11-7.2 6.1-13.8 13-21.5 18.5-2.5 0.9-11.8 3.1-11.1-0.3 4.6-13.1 9.3-26.3 13.9-39.4-6.6 0-13.2 0-19.8 0 2.1-2.8 3.4-6.9 6-8.9 8.1 0.2 16.2-0.3 24.2 0.3 6.7 2.8 1.3 10.4 0.2 15.4-2 6-4.1 12.1-6.1 18.1 12.3-11.3 24.7-22.5 37-33.8 3.7 0 7.4 0 11.1 0z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Дальше можно делать анимацию, используя `stroke-dashoffset`, `stroke-dasharray`

Конечно лучше и правильней научиться сначала делать вручную, чтобы понимать, как это работает, а затем уже использовать библиотеки.

В противном случае весьма вероятен вариант, что при ошибке в SVG никакая библиотека не спасёт. И вы не будете понимать причины неработоспособности приложения.

**Ниже вариант последовательной анимации букв.**

Для начала анимации кликните внутри прямоугольника

```css
.el{
     stroke:#ACACAC;
 stroke-width:2;
 fill:none;
 
}
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="560" height="200" viewBox="0 0 280 100" style="border:1px solid grey;">

 <g id="STACK"  transform="scale(0.83640582,1.1955919)" >
    <path class="el" stroke-dasharray="0,319" d="M81.1 21.5C81.1 33.9 59.2 31.7 62.5 19.4 47.6 19.1 60.9 36.3 61.2 44.1 63.3 54.4 53.3 61.8 44.2 63.4 32.2 65.9 18.4 65.6 7.9 58.6-2.4 50.7 8 37.1 18.8 38.9c6-0.3 12.1-0.1 18.1-0.2 1.5 3.1 4.4 7.2-1.3 5.7-5.9 0.2-14-1.3-17.1 5.1-0.2 10.9 16.3 11.7 23.6 7.1 9.2-6.3 1.7-17.9-0.5-25.9-4.4-11.1 7.7-18.4 17.4-17.6 6.8 0.5 15.3-2.3 20.4 3.7 1.1 1.3 1.7 3.1 1.7 4.8zM141.1 12.9" >
  <animate id="S_let" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click;K_let.end+0.25s" dur="0.8s" values="0,319;319,0" fill="freeze"/>
 </path> 
    <path class="el" stroke-dasharray="0,354" d="m141.1 12.9c-1.6 3-3.2 6-4.8 8.9-4.4 0-8.8 0-13.2 0-4.2 11.3-7.7 22.9-12.5 34-4.4 8.4-14.5 6.9-22.4 7-5.1 0-10.2 0-15.3 0 1.1-7.2 7.7-10 14-7.6 3.7 0.6 7.3 1.2 11 1.7C102.1 45.2 106.2 33.5 110.4 21.8 102.1 22.1 93.7 21.2 85.5 22.5 79 21.5 75 37.4 80.4 33.6 85.3 20.8 106.5 32.5 95.8 42.6 86.4 50 69.1 42.3 71.3 29.5 72.8 17 86.8 11.8 97.9 12.9c14.4 0 28.8 0 43.2 0z" >
    <animate id="T_let" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="S_let.end+0.25s" dur="0.8s" values="0,354;354,0" fill="freeze"/>
 </path> 
    <path class="el" stroke-dasharray="0,423"  d="m223.6 38.7c-2.4 7.7-11.5 5.3-17.6 5.7-4 0-8.1 0-12.1 0-2.2 6.2-4.4 12.3-6.7 18.5-4.2 0-8.5 0-12.7 0 2.2-6.2 4.4-12.3 6.7-18.5-3.6 0-7.3 0-10.9 0-9.6 11.6-23.2 23.9-39.5 21.1-14.5-2.7-5.9-20.6 4.7-22.5 9.7-4.2 20.5-4.4 30.9-4.3 7.2-8.6 14.3-17.2 21.5-25.8 5.7 0 11.4 0 17.1 0-3.1 8.6-6.1 17.2-9.2 25.8 9.3 0 18.5 0 27.8 0zM190.6 18.8c-5.2 6.6-10.4 13.3-15.5 19.9 2.8-0.8 8.1 2 8.7-2.1 2.3-5.9 4.5-11.9 6.8-17.8zm-29 25.6c-8.4 0-22.8 0.9-22.9 11.9 7.5 5.5 18.1-6.6 22.9-11.9z" >
   <animate id="A_let" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="T_let.end+0.25s" dur="1s" values="0,423;423,0" fill="freeze"/>
 </path> 
    <path class="el" stroke-dasharray="0,247" d="m261.8 21.6c0.1 12.7-22.1 10.4-18.8-2.1-13.2 1.1-22.9 17.2-18.4 29.5 5 10 17.5 8 26.9 8.2 3.1 0.5 12.1-1.9 7.1 3.5-5.6 3.8-12.8 1.6-19.2 2.2-10.9 0-25.4-1.6-30-13.2-4.4-15 8.4-29.3 21.8-34.1 7.9-2.9 16.8-3.4 25-2 3.1 1.4 5.7 4.5 5.6 8z" >
    <animate id="C_let" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="A_let.end+0.25s" dur="0.8s" values="0,247;247,0" fill="freeze"/>
 </path> 
    <path class="el" stroke-dasharray="0,361" d="m330.7 12.9c-9.7 8.6-19.3 17.2-29 25.8 8.1-1.9 8.7 6.6 5.5 11.9-0.6 2.9-4.5 8 1.1 6.5 3.8 0 7.6 0 11.4 0-3 7.8-12.7 5.2-19.3 5.7-5.9 1.5-10.8-3.2-7.2-8.9 1.2-3.7 2.4-7.3 3.7-11-7.2 6.1-13.8 13-21.5 18.5-2.5 0.9-11.8 3.1-11.1-0.3 4.6-13.1 9.3-26.3 13.9-39.4-6.6 0-13.2 0-19.8 0 2.1-2.8 3.4-6.9 6-8.9 8.1 0.2 16.2-0.3 24.2 0.3 6.7 2.8 1.3 10.4 0.2 15.4-2 6-4.1 12.1-6.1 18.1 12.3-11.3 24.7-22.5 37-33.8 3.7 0 7.4 0 11.1 0z" >
    <animate id="K_let" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="C_let.end+0.25s" dur="0.8s" values="0,361;361,0" fill="freeze"/>
 </path>    
   
  </g> 
  
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: очень крутые все ответы, действительно помогли разобраться!

Answer (score 4):

### Анимация букв SVG с помощью Anime.js

Как было видно из первых ответов, чтобы добиться анимации с помощью `stroke-dashoffset` или `stroke-dasharray` важно точно узнать длину контура для каждой буквы.

Будем анимировать с помощью **Anime.js** слово STACK

Ниже код небольшой утилитки с помощью которой можно узнать  длину любого `path`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<div> 
 <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
</div>   
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" > 
 
         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="1" 
         
   d="m59.3 12.8 6.4 20.3q-5.3-4.5-9.5-6.9-4.2-2.4-6.8-2.4-2 0-3.1 1.1-1.1 1.1-1.1 3 0 2.4 2.4 4.3 2.4 1.9 7.5 3.4 11.3 3.4 15.3 6.7 4 3.3 4 8.4 0 8.3-8.1 13.6-8.1 5.3-20.9 5.3-6.5 0-12.9-2.3-6.4-2.4-11.8-6.7V69.6L13.9 49.3q4.7 3.8 9.2 5.9 4.6 2 8.3 2 4 0 6.2-1.7 2.2-1.7 2.2-4.7 0-2.8-1.8-4.5-1.8-1.7-8-3.6-9-2.9-13.5-6.8-4.4-4-4.4-9.3 0-6.7 5.9-11 5.9-4.3 15.4-4.3 6.2 0 12.2 2.2 5.9 2.2 12.2 6.9z" />
</svg> 
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
</html>
```

Для букв STACK следующие значения:

S - 317
 T - 355
 A  - 342
 C   - 270
 K  - 375

Подставляем эти значения `stroke-dashoffset="317"` (для буквы `S`) в каждый `path`

Далее используем `anime.js`

*Для повтора анимации один раз прописываем в скрипте `loop: false`*

```js
anime({
  targets: '.line-drawing-demo .lines path',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 1500,
  delay: function(e1, i) { return i * 250 },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: false
});
```

```css
.el{
     stroke:crimson;
 stroke-width:2;
 fill:none;
 
}
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div class="line-drawing-demo">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 350 100" style="border:1px solid grey;">
 
  <g class="lines" >
 
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="317px" d="m59.3 12.8 6.4 20.3q-5.3-4.5-9.5-6.9-4.2-2.4-6.8-2.4-2 0-3.1 1.1-1.1 1.1-1.1 3 0 2.4 2.4 4.3 2.4 1.9 7.5 3.4 11.3 3.4 15.3 6.7 4 3.3 4 8.4 0 8.3-8.1 13.6-8.1 5.3-20.9 5.3-6.5 0-12.9-2.3-6.4-2.4-11.8-6.7V69.6L13.9 49.3q4.7 3.8 9.2 5.9 4.6 2 8.3 2 4 0 6.2-1.7 2.2-1.7 2.2-4.7 0-2.8-1.8-4.5-1.8-1.7-8-3.6-9-2.9-13.5-6.8-4.4-4-4.4-9.3 0-6.7 5.9-11 5.9-4.3 15.4-4.3 6.2 0 12.2 2.2 5.9 2.2 12.2 6.9z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="355px" d="M136.9 11.5 118.6 47.3 116.2 20 105.6 61.9 121.7 69.6 87 67.7 98.2 64.3 85.5 19.2 81.9 52.3 74.5 15.7Z" />
   
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="342px" d="m171 38-5.3-15.1-5.1 18.6zm30.5 21.7-33 10.2 8.4-11.3-2.4-8.4-12.3 0.9-3.6 9.8 5.3 4.2-35.9 2.6 8.7-6.5 11.6-45.2-6.6-4.3 44.5 1.5-10.4 3.7 18.2 40.6z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="270px" d="m256.7 40.5-4 26.3-1.6-10.7q-5.5 6.5-12.1 9.9-6.6 3.4-13.8 3.4-4.7 0-9.2-1.9-4.5-2-8.1-5.7-4.3-4.3-6.6-9.7-2.3-5.4-2.3-11 0-7.8 3.3-14.2 3.3-6.4 9.3-10.5 4-2.7 8.7-4 4.7-1.3 10.1-1.3 5 0 9.2 1.6 4.3 1.6 8 4.7l2.2-6.3 3.9 20.7q-2.5-3.6-5.9-5.5-3.4-1.9-7.3-1.9-4.5 0-7.3 2.7-2.8 2.6-2.8 7 0 4.6 3.4 7.8 3.4 3.1 8.6 3.1 3.2 0 6.6-1.1 3.4-1.1 7.4-3.4z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="375px" d="m329.1 68.8-30.1-3.7 6-3.9-17.6-18.1-2 0.4 4.1 20.1 6.4 6.8-38.1-4.3 6.8-5 3.6-41.2-7.4-4.7 30.5-3.7-8.5 6.6 2.5 16 13.4-15.9-3.7-4.6 27.7 1-19.7 15.8z" />
</g>   
 </svg>

</div>
```

*Для повторения в цикле: `loop: true`*

```js
anime({
  targets: '.line-drawing-demo .lines path',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 1500,
  delay: function(e1, i) { return i * 250 },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

```css
.el{
     stroke:black;
 stroke-width:2;
 fill:none;
 
}
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div class="line-drawing-demo">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 350 100" style="border:1px solid grey;">
 
  <g class="lines" >
 
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="317px" d="m59.3 12.8 6.4 20.3q-5.3-4.5-9.5-6.9-4.2-2.4-6.8-2.4-2 0-3.1 1.1-1.1 1.1-1.1 3 0 2.4 2.4 4.3 2.4 1.9 7.5 3.4 11.3 3.4 15.3 6.7 4 3.3 4 8.4 0 8.3-8.1 13.6-8.1 5.3-20.9 5.3-6.5 0-12.9-2.3-6.4-2.4-11.8-6.7V69.6L13.9 49.3q4.7 3.8 9.2 5.9 4.6 2 8.3 2 4 0 6.2-1.7 2.2-1.7 2.2-4.7 0-2.8-1.8-4.5-1.8-1.7-8-3.6-9-2.9-13.5-6.8-4.4-4-4.4-9.3 0-6.7 5.9-11 5.9-4.3 15.4-4.3 6.2 0 12.2 2.2 5.9 2.2 12.2 6.9z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="355px" d="M136.9 11.5 118.6 47.3 116.2 20 105.6 61.9 121.7 69.6 87 67.7 98.2 64.3 85.5 19.2 81.9 52.3 74.5 15.7Z" />
   
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="342px" d="m171 38-5.3-15.1-5.1 18.6zm30.5 21.7-33 10.2 8.4-11.3-2.4-8.4-12.3 0.9-3.6 9.8 5.3 4.2-35.9 2.6 8.7-6.5 11.6-45.2-6.6-4.3 44.5 1.5-10.4 3.7 18.2 40.6z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="270px" d="m256.7 40.5-4 26.3-1.6-10.7q-5.5 6.5-12.1 9.9-6.6 3.4-13.8 3.4-4.7 0-9.2-1.9-4.5-2-8.1-5.7-4.3-4.3-6.6-9.7-2.3-5.4-2.3-11 0-7.8 3.3-14.2 3.3-6.4 9.3-10.5 4-2.7 8.7-4 4.7-1.3 10.1-1.3 5 0 9.2 1.6 4.3 1.6 8 4.7l2.2-6.3 3.9 20.7q-2.5-3.6-5.9-5.5-3.4-1.9-7.3-1.9-4.5 0-7.3 2.7-2.8 2.6-2.8 7 0 4.6 3.4 7.8 3.4 3.1 8.6 3.1 3.2 0 6.6-1.1 3.4-1.1 7.4-3.4z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="375px" d="m329.1 68.8-30.1-3.7 6-3.9-17.6-18.1-2 0.4 4.1 20.1 6.4 6.8-38.1-4.3 6.8-5 3.6-41.2-7.4-4.7 30.5-3.7-8.5 6.6 2.5 16 13.4-15.9-3.7-4.6 27.7 1-19.7 15.8z" />
</g>   
 </svg>

</div>
```

Для прорисовки каждой буквы по отдельности нужно увеличить время задержки

```
delay: function(e1, i) { return i * 1400 }
```

```js
anime({
  targets: '.line-drawing-demo .lines path',
  strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
  duration: 1500,
  delay: function(e1, i) { return i * 1400 },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true
});
```

```css
.el{
     stroke:cyan;
 stroke-width:2;
 fill:none;
 
}
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div class="line-drawing-demo">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="200" viewBox="0 0 350 100" style="border:1px solid grey;">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#111111" />
  <g class="lines" >
 
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="317px" d="m59.3 12.8 6.4 20.3q-5.3-4.5-9.5-6.9-4.2-2.4-6.8-2.4-2 0-3.1 1.1-1.1 1.1-1.1 3 0 2.4 2.4 4.3 2.4 1.9 7.5 3.4 11.3 3.4 15.3 6.7 4 3.3 4 8.4 0 8.3-8.1 13.6-8.1 5.3-20.9 5.3-6.5 0-12.9-2.3-6.4-2.4-11.8-6.7V69.6L13.9 49.3q4.7 3.8 9.2 5.9 4.6 2 8.3 2 4 0 6.2-1.7 2.2-1.7 2.2-4.7 0-2.8-1.8-4.5-1.8-1.7-8-3.6-9-2.9-13.5-6.8-4.4-4-4.4-9.3 0-6.7 5.9-11 5.9-4.3 15.4-4.3 6.2 0 12.2 2.2 5.9 2.2 12.2 6.9z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="355px" d="M136.9 11.5 118.6 47.3 116.2 20 105.6 61.9 121.7 69.6 87 67.7 98.2 64.3 85.5 19.2 81.9 52.3 74.5 15.7Z" />
   
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="342px" d="m171 38-5.3-15.1-5.1 18.6zm30.5 21.7-33 10.2 8.4-11.3-2.4-8.4-12.3 0.9-3.6 9.8 5.3 4.2-35.9 2.6 8.7-6.5 11.6-45.2-6.6-4.3 44.5 1.5-10.4 3.7 18.2 40.6z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="270px" d="m256.7 40.5-4 26.3-1.6-10.7q-5.5 6.5-12.1 9.9-6.6 3.4-13.8 3.4-4.7 0-9.2-1.9-4.5-2-8.1-5.7-4.3-4.3-6.6-9.7-2.3-5.4-2.3-11 0-7.8 3.3-14.2 3.3-6.4 9.3-10.5 4-2.7 8.7-4 4.7-1.3 10.1-1.3 5 0 9.2 1.6 4.3 1.6 8 4.7l2.2-6.3 3.9 20.7q-2.5-3.6-5.9-5.5-3.4-1.9-7.3-1.9-4.5 0-7.3 2.7-2.8 2.6-2.8 7 0 4.6 3.4 7.8 3.4 3.1 8.6 3.1 3.2 0 6.6-1.1 3.4-1.1 7.4-3.4z" />
  
    <path class="el"  stroke-dashoffset="375px" d="m329.1 68.8-30.1-3.7 6-3.9-17.6-18.1-2 0.4 4.1 20.1 6.4 6.8-38.1-4.3 6.8-5 3.6-41.2-7.4-4.7 30.5-3.7-8.5 6.6 2.5 16 13.4-15.9-3.7-4.6 27.7 1-19.7 15.8z" />
</g>   
 </svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Вариант без конвертирования букв текста в векторные `path`

*В SVG все элементы являются векторными объектами и текст тоже.*

Как только мы добавляем текст в SVG с помощью тега `<text>` он становится векторным объектом, который получает координаты, и к которому можно применить `stroke-dashooffset`
  Это свойство используется для анимации рисования букв.

Текст включенный в SVG можно стилизовать внешними правилами CSS.

В примере ниже я подключил гуугловский текст  `Tangerine`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">`

```html
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 150px;
  font-weigth:bold;
  
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="svg1"  version="1.1" width="500" height="200"
        viewBox="0 0 500 200"     
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="background:dodgerblue">
      
       <text stroke-dasharray="500 500" stroke-dashoffset="500" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" dy="1em" >
      Stackoverflow
      <animate begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
        attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
        values="500;0;0;500;500" fill="freeze" />
    </text>
            
 </svg>
  </body>
```